# Search if value in cell (i,j) exists in another sheets, else i+1 until same value is found

Tags: vba, excel, loops, runtime-error

I have an issue with my VBA script which I'm not able to resolve, despite of all the researches I've made (Indeed, I tried to modify all the vba scripts which were near what I'm looking for, but it doesn't work).

Thank you very much for your help !

I have 2 sheets.

For the first one (*ActiveSheet*), I have a list.
For example :

1. Beurre
2. Creme fraiche
3. ***Fromage***
4. Oeufs
5. Yaourts

In the second one ("*Add value*"), I have this list :

1. Chocolat
2. Carotte
3. Haricot
4. ***Fromage***
5. Endive

I want the script to verify if the first value which is the sheet ("*Add Value*") exists in the *ActiveSheet*.
If it doesn't, it takes the second value in "Add Value" to make this verification. And so on with the other lines.
The loop has to stop when the script finds the same value. Then it does an action (MsgBox, for example).

For example, when the script researches "Chocolat" (the first line of the sheet "*Add Value*") in the ActiveSheet, it won't find it : it will use the second word to make this reasearch until it uses world "***Fromage***" which also exist in the second sheet.
It does the action (the msgbox), then quit the loop to continue with the other called macro which are in the script.

Moreover, I would like to choose the columns of the cell from "*Add Value*" each time I call the macro. Indeed, there will be several lists in this sheet.

Here is my macro. The issue is that I get the **error 424** on the ligne `If Not FindString Is Nothing Then`

```
 Public Sub Var()

 Dim plage As Variant
     Set plage = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")

 Dim col As Integer

 Dim Ligne As Integer
     Set Ligne = 2

 Dim FindString As String
     Set FindString = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Add Value").Cells(Ligne, col).Value
      End Sub


Sub Boucle_Ajout(col)

With plage

  Do

     If Not FindString Is Nothing Then

        'do
     Else

       Ligne = Ligne + 1

     End If

  Loop While Not FindString Is Nothing

End With

End Sub
```

Then when I call the Macro, I only have to choose the column.
For example :

```
Call Boucle_Ajout(1)
```

Thank you very much for your help, because I am sick of not finding the solution.

PS : sorry for my english, I'm french.

Comment: The "Hello" has been deleted, so Hello !

Comment: Even if I change this into "If Not plage.Find(FindString) Is Nothing Then", it doesn't work.

Comment: It would help if you submitted code or at least a screenshot.
Is the number included in each cell? If so it won't find a match between 
3. Fromage ... and 
4. Fromage

Comment: [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) will put you on the right track :)

Comment: What should this look like when it's finished?    You just need to know if each item has a match on the other sheet?  I don't understand ` : it will use the second word to make this reasearch until it uses world `Fromage" which also exist in the second sheet`

Comment: I see a few issues.  For example, `Set` is used when assigning values to objects, not for use with variables like that.  I'm going to go out on a limb here and guess that you have named one of your worksheets "ActiveSheet", is that correct?  When learning VBA, a good starting place is tutorials to get you up to speed on the basics.  Click [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#odc_Office14_ta_GettingStartedWithVBAInExcel2010_WhatNext) for one.  Also check out the SO [Tour] as well as [how to ask] and [mcve].  _Welcome!_

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the lines without numbers are in A1 to A5, this works:
[image]

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Const THECOLUMN = "A1"
Sub FindLineInOtherSheet()
    Dim activeSheetRange As Range
    Dim addValueRange As Range
    Dim activeSheetLastRow As Integer
    Dim addValueLastRow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim activeSheetCell As String
    Dim addValueCell As String
    '*
    '* Setup
    '*
    Set activeSheetRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("activeSheet").Range(THECOLUMN)
    activeSheetLastRow = findLastRow("activeSheet", THECOLUMN)
    addValueLastRow = findLastRow("addValue", THECOLUMN)
    '*
    '* Loop through each cell in addValue for each cell in activeSheet
    '*
    For i = 1 To activeSheetLastRow
        Set addValueRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("addValue").Range(THECOLUMN)
        activeSheetCell = activeSheetRange.Value
        For n = 1 To addValueLastRow
            addValueCell = addValueRange.Value
            If addValueCell = activeSheetCell Then
                MsgBox ("Trouvé " & addValueCell)
            End If
            Set addValueRange = addValueRange.Offset(1, 0) 'Next row
        Next n
        Set activeSheetRange = activeSheetRange.Offset(1, 0)
    Next i
End Sub
Function findLastRow(Sheetname As String, ColumnName As String) As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim r As Range
    Dim WS As Worksheet

    Set WS = Worksheets(Sheetname)
    lastRow = WS.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    '*
    '* Search backwards till we find a cell that is not empty
    '*
    Set r = WS.Range(ColumnName).Rows(lastRow)
    While IsEmpty(r)
        Set r = r.Offset(-1, 0)
    Wend
    lastRow = r.Row
    Set WS = Nothing
    findLastRow = lastRow
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! I will test it and tell you if it works. In fact, activesheet is the active sheet. To reply to your question, I need to find if a value exist to insert another value before it.